# Using SVG package in Latex (pdflatex) on macOS Catalina

Tags: pdftex, svg, inkscape, macos

Compilation fails after `inkscape: command not found` but I'm able to convert svg manually in terminal.

The following command works  and produce the `img.pdf` file.

```
inkscape img.svg --export-type=pdf
```

The following command also work :

```
inkscape --version
```

Inkscape 1.0beta1 (32d4812, 2019-09-19)

this is my *mwe*

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \includesvg{img}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The command I run to compile :

```
pdflatex  -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder -output-directory="/Users/x/Desktop/test"  "/Users/x/Desktop/test/test.tex"
```

error :

```
inkscape: command not found
```

Inkscape version: Inkscape 1.0beta1 (32d4812, 2019-09-19)

OS : macOS Catalina 10.15.1 (19B88)

Iterm2 : Build 3.3.7

Shell : zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0)

full logs

```
pdflatex  -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder -output-directory="/Users/x/Desktop/test"  "/Users/x/Desktop/test/test.tex"
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/Users/x/Desktop/test/test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-french/french.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/scalefnt.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/todonotes/todonotes.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.d
ef
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.
tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryshadows.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryfadings.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryfadings
.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/bookmark.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdfescape.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/bkm-pdftex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjcalc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/tc-pdftex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pppdftex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/afterpage.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/epsfig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/lscape.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/comment/comment.sty
Excluding comment 'comment')
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryarrows.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/french.lbx)
(/Users/x/Desktop/test/test.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/pdflscape.sty)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
No file test.bbl.
/Users/x/Desktop/test/test.tex:139: Undefined control sequence.
l.139   \includesvg
                   [width=\textwidth]{img}
/Users/x/Desktop/test/test.tex:139: Missing number, treated as zer
o.
<to be read again>
                   ]
l.139   \includesvg[width=\textwidth]
                                     {img}
/Users/x/Desktop/test/test.tex:139: Illegal unit of measure (pt in
serted).
<to be read again>
                   ]
l.139   \includesvg[width=\textwidth]
                                     {img}
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}pdfTeX
warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{figure.1}) has been
already used, duplicate ignored

\@EveryShipout@Output ...@Org@Shipout \box \@cclv

l.143 \end{document}
                    ] (/Users/x/Desktop/test/test.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information){/usr/local/texlive/2019/te
xmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}</usr/local/texlive/2019/texm
f-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfcc1095.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-
dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1095.pfb>
Output written on /Users/x/Desktop/test/test.pdf (1 page, 29082 by
tes).
SyncTeX written on /Users/x/Desktop/test/test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on /Users/x/Desktop/test/test.log.
```

Comment: I do have a similar issue with MacOS macOS Catalina 10.15.1. I am using Inkscape 1.0 as well. I can run the ``inkscape`` command from the terminal and it exports the file well. However, when it is called within the LaTeX, I get similar error ``sh: inkscape: command not found system returned with code 32512``

Comment: Well, I fixed it by giving the additional option in ``\usepackage[inkscapeexe=/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/MacOS/inkscape,inkscapearea=page]{svg}``. I have created an alias in my computer, where ``which inkscape`` returns ``/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/MacOS/inkscape``. However, still I needed to pass the full path in my TeX to be able to compile. I hope someone can figure out why this is happening in Catalina.